# Listview with two Layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i want to create a Listview with two different Layouts.
The first item should have a black background with a white font and the second reversed.
The third a balck background again and so on.
Any one a idea?

Comment: try  to post your adapter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use a custom `Adapter`.
Using that, you can create custom layouts for your `ListViews`.

Try having a look at these two tutorials, they helped me out a lot:

Creating a ListView using SimpleAdapter: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/

Applying alternate row colors using SimpleAdapter: http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/

Good luck.

Comment: yea I already made a customadapter...
so should i make two layoutfiles and two customadapter?